# HighCharts series data won't load array

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, highcharts

I am trying to implement HighCharts into my app, but when I get the data from my server and put it into an array, the series data parameter doesn't read it, and I get nothing on the y-axis.

Here is my code:

```
$('.icon-signal').click(function(){
  var title = $(this).data('title');
  $('#dialogs').html('');
  $('#dialogs').load(dialogs + 'empty.html', function() {
    $('#genericModal').modal();
    $('#genericModal').css('width', '700px')
    $('#okButton').hide();
    $('.cancel').html('Close');
    $('h3#genericHeader').html(title);
    var dateRange;
    $.ajax({
      url: ROOT+'intel/date-range',
      data: {
        partid: partId
      },
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      success: function(data)
      {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        var categories = [];
        var seriesA = [];
        $.each(data, function(i, v){
          $.each(v, function(i2, v2){
            if(i2 == 'date')
            {
              categories.push(v2)
            }
            if(i2 == 'average')
            {
              seriesA.push(v2)
            }
          })
        })
        $('#genericBody').highcharts({
          chart: {
            type: 'line'
          },
          title: {
            text: title
          },
          xAxis: {
            categories: categories
          },
          yAxis: {
            title: {
              text: '£s'
            }
          },
          series: [{
            name: 'Average',
            data: seriesA
          }]
        })
      }
    })
  })
})
```

If I alert the array I get what is expected: `31.53, 48.60, 97.31`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to parseInt v2, embarrassing...

```
...
if(i2 == 'date')
{
    v2 = parseInt(v2)
    categories.push(v2)
}
...
```